# Unexpected return value from recursive function

Tags: java

I wrote a short piece of code with the purpose of setting an integer value. However, it does not seem to return the correct value. For example, for the following inputs I would expect it to work like so.

> Please enter a positive integer value
>   -458
>   Please enter a positive valid integer
>   58
>   58

However, the actual output is the following.

> Please enter a positive integer value
>   -458
>   Please enter a positive valid integer
>   58
>   -458

In this example why does it return `-458` instead of `58`?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IncorectValueReturned {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer value");
        System.out.println(setInt());
    }

    private int setInt() {
        int i = -1;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            i = sc.nextInt();
            if(i < 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive valid integer");
                setInt();
            }
        } catch(InputMismatchException iME) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive valid integer");
            setInt();
        }
        sc.close();
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IncorectValueReturned iVR = new IncorectValueReturned();
        iVR.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never change the first `i` that was invalid, you need to recover the value of the recursive calls

```
i = setInt();
```

And of course, you should not redeclare this Scanner over and over.
Use a Instance variable instead.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private int setInt() {
    int i = -1;
    try {
        i = sc.nextInt();
        if(i < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive valid integer");
            i = setInt();
        }
    } catch(InputMismatchException iME) {
        //Clear the scanner of this value
        sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive valid integer");
        i = setInt();
    }
    return i;
}
```

And close the scanner when you are done with it.

Careful, a value that throws an exception will remain in the input, you need to read it, I used `Scanner.next()` to remove a bad input like a a value bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: With this fix do you know why if you were to input a number bigger `Integer.MAX_VALUE` it throws a `StackOverflowError`?

Comment: @Dan, this throws a `InputMismatchException` like the doc state : _"if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range"_

Comment: @Dan, my bad, you need to flush the scanner since the Exception (`InputMismatchException`) leave the overflow number, check the edit, the catch part

Answer (score 1):

You didn't assign `i` the new value from `SetInt()`.

```
if(i < 0) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive valid integer");
    i = setInt(); //  <- HERE
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I didn't see that XD

Comment: Damn, to slow. There is the same problem in the catch. And this method is a one shot only.